# Gambler's ruin: verifying Markov property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, formal-proofs

> Gambler's ruin: the gambler starts with $\$i$, where $ 1<i<N$. He wins $\$1$ with probability $p$ and loses $\$1$ with probability $1-p$. When he reaches $0$ (ruin) or $N$ (win), he stops playing.

Durrett's book on Stochastic Processes states:

> Let $X_n$ be the amount of money after $n$ plays. For any possible history of your wealth, $i_0, \ldots , i_{n-1},i,$ $$ P(X_{n+1}=i+1 | X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)=p $$
>   since to increase your wealth by $1$ unit you have to win the next bet.

Although I see the point, I don't know how to prove the Markov property:
$$ P(X_{n+1}=j | X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)=P(X_{n+1}=j | X_n=i) $$
given the following hypothesis for the probability distribution of the sequence $\{X_n\}$:

- If $1<i<N$, then $P(X_{n+1}= i+1 | X_n=i)=p$ and $\ P(X_{n+1}=i-1 | X_n=i)=1-p$
- If $i=1$ or $i=N$, then $P(X_{n+1}= i | X_n=i)= 1$

How do I prove that the Markov property holds?

Edit: the states space is $\{0, \ldots, N \}$ and the probability distribution for $X_0$ is considered given

Comment: The Markov property cannot be proven from those hypotheses.

Comment: Either the property holds or doesn't hold. What do you mean it can't be proven? Doesn't the hypothesis define a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of random variables? Lets add to the question that the probability distribution for $X_0$ is given

Comment: You haven't defined the full distribution, and whether the property holds depends on the full distribution. The distribution of $X_{n+1}$ conditional on $X_n$ is not enough to determine the full distribution.You need to add something along the lines of the Markov property to the hypotheses.

Comment: The way I see it, the distribution for $X_1$ is given by $P(X_1=j)=\sum_{k=0}^N P(X_1=j | X_0=k)$ and in this way we can recursively define the distribution for $X_2, X_3,$ etc. starting from the $X_0$ distribution. If I am wrong please tell me how

Answer (score 1):

You can see that Markov property holds, using Durret's condition:

> Let $X_n$ be the amount of money after $n$ plays. For any possible history of your wealth, $i_0, \ldots , i_{n-1},i,$ $$ P(X_{n+1}=i+1 | X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)=p $$
>   since to increase your wealth by $1$ unit you have to win the next bet.

Indeed, writing:
$$P(X_{n+1}= i+i | X_n=i) = \frac{P(X_{n+1}= i+i , X_n=i)}{P(X_n=i)} =  \frac{\sum_{i_k, k \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}}P(X_{n+1}=i+1 , X_n=i, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)}{\sum_{i_k, k \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}}P( X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)} = \frac{\sum_{i_k, k \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}}p\cdot P( X_n=i, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)}{\sum_{i_k, k \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}}P( X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)} \\
=p\frac{\sum_{i_k, k \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}} P( X_n=i, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)}{\sum_{i_k, k \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}}P( X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)} = p$$

where we considered the set of every possible outcomes in the $(n-1)$ bets in the sum and used that

$$  p = P(X_{n+1}=i+1 | X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0) = \frac{P(X_{n+1}=i+1 , X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)}{P( X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)}$$
implies
$$ p\cdot P( X_n=i, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0) \\= P(X_{n+1}=i+1 , X_n=i , X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0)  $$